# Error while converting rgb to lab : python

Tags: python, image-processing

```
import skimage 
from skimage import io, color
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndi

rgb = io.imread('img.jpg')
lab = color.rgb2lab(skimage.img_as_float(rgb))
l_chan1 = lab[:,:,0]
l_chan1 /= np.max(np.abs(l_chan1))
l_chan_med = ndi.median_filter(l_chan1, size=5)
skimage.io.imshow(l_chan_med)
```

I am trying to do some image processing. While i was changing the color scheme, i am  getting an error for rgb2lab function. " color.rgb2lab module object has no attribute 'rgb2lab'. I have imported all the required libraries.Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import skimage 
from skimage import io
from skimage.color import rgb2lab
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndi

rgb = io.imread('img.jpg')
lab = rgb2lab(skimage.img_as_float(rgb))
l_chan1 = lab[:,:,0]
l_chan1 /= np.max(np.abs(l_chan1))
l_chan_med = ndi.median_filter(l_chan1, size=5)
skimage.io.imshow(l_chan_med)
```

Comment: @ANUSHADEVI What's the error message? Could you please show me the whole trace back?

Comment: @ANUSHADEVI Here is a link for you. Follow the examples in it and if there is still error, try to reinstall skimage package. http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.rgb2lab

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong, but your code runs fine on my machine.  Python 2.7.6, OS X Yosemite.  I would try reinstalling scikit-image.